# How to correctly match tags containing a word in regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to remove automatically tags containing "download", "free" or "release" from the track title in Python using RegEx and I am already close to the solution, but I don't know why the RegEx tester gives me a match far before the actual tag I would like to have removed.

Instead of matching only the "[Free Download]" from the track title, it matches every tag before too. I would like to use it to automatically tag downloaded tracks from youtube-dl, as SoundCloud and YouTube doesn't mostly give good meta.

Here is my current RegEx: https://regex101.com/r/yaJ9yC/3

Comment: If you define everything in brackets or parentheses as tags then it finds all tags containing "download" as requested. What is the problem?

Comment: This looks like homework assignment - if you want to get assistance, you need to try something and explain where you have difficulties. We wont provide a solution, but might put you on the right track to find it yourself.

Comment: @IliyanBobev no, it's rather a thing that I'm doing for my own music library, I want to use it to automatically add ID3 tags for downloaded tracks from youtube-dl :)

Comment: @MichaelButscher the problem are the "innocent" tags like these containing "feat." or "mix", those are more unpredictable than the one I want to have matched and removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `*` alone is greedy. It matches the longest possibility on the line. For example: `[\(\[]` matches `(`, then `.*` matches all `Astronaut REMIX) [FREE` and `download.*[\)\]]` matches the `DOWNLOAD]`.

Non greedy repetion in python `re` library is done by `*?`. But because matching starts on the left site, for the example above it still does not work and you need to exclude the brackets and square brackets on the left site:

```
 [\(\[][^\(\[]*download.*?[\)\]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out using as example `[\(\[].*?download.*?[\)\]]` as you suggested, but it still matched the other tags too.

Comment: Sorry, my first idea was incorrect, I edited the answer.